# Make a set with an empty dictionary return False in Python

Tags: python, django, dictionary

If someone doesn't fill out any forms in my Django formset, it returns `[{}]`.

How can I test whether this dictionary within a set has been populated or not? Something like the following, though this doesn't work as the empty dictionary seems to make the list return True:

```
form_output_when_empty = [{}]
if form_output_when_empty:
    print "This should not print"
    # currently this prints out, which is not what I want!
else:
    print "This should print."

form_output_when_filled = [{'name': 'John'}]
if form_output_when_filled:
    print "This should print"
else:
    print "This should not print"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python an empty dictionary or an empty list are "false", but a list containing and empty dictionary is instead "true".

To do the check that you want therefore you need to enter the list and check the element:

```
 if form and form[0]:
    ...
```

this will enter the `if` body only if the list has at least one dictionary and the first dictionary is not empty